# Can't get rid of whitespace at bottom of css parallax page

Tags: html, css, parallax

I can't seem to be able to get rid of the whitespace at the bottom of this page. I've tried the regular padding/margin solutions. I think it might have to do with the fact that i'm using css perspective values. Can anyone figure this out?

Sorry, This is the first time i've posted here so i shared the site as well as the code.
http://jesseellingson.com/Reflections_Test/

```
<body>
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <img src="img/site111.png">
    </div>

    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <img src="img/site222.png">
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--text">
        <p class="title">REFLECTIONS</p>
        <p class="year">2016</p>
        <p class="info3">March 22-28</p>
        <p class="info4">Ferry Building Gallery</p>
        <p class="info5">1414 Argyle Ave</p>
        <p class="info6">West Vancouver</p>
        <p class="info7">BC V7T 1C2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--3">
        <img src="img/site333.png">
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--text2">
        <p class="about">
            There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--4">
        <img src="img/site444.png">
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--sm">
        <div class="icons">
            <ul class="soc">
                <li><a class="soc-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/CapReflections/?fref=ts"></a></li>
                <li><a class="soc-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a class="soc-instagram soc-icon-last" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    body, html {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-size: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.title {
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 49%;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: .5vw;
    font-size: 6.3vw;
}

.year {
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 8%;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: .2%;
    padding-right: .5vw;
}

.info {
    padding: 2%;
    margin-top: 4%;
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 4vw;
    line-height: 130%;
}

.info3, .info4, .info5, .info6, .info7 {
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.info3 {
    margin-top: 4%;
    width: 20%;
}

.info4 {
    width: 34%;
}

.info5 {
    width: 26%;
}

.info6 {
    width: 26%;
}

.info7 {
    width: 19%;
}

.about {
    margin-top: 63%;
    width: 45%;
    padding: 4%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 135%;
}


/*///////////////SOCIAL MEDIA ICONS////////////////*/
.icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 175%;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'si';
    src: url('../img/socicon.eot');
    src: url('../img/socicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../img/socicon.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../img/socicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../img/socicon.svg#icomoonregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family:si;
        src: url(../img/socicon.svg) format(svg);
    }
}

.soc {
/*    overflow:hidden;*/
    margin:0; padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

.soc li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}

.soc li a {
    font-family:si!important;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;

    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);

    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 13vw;
    height: 13vw;
    line-height: 13vw;
    font-size: 6vw;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: none;
    background-color: none;
}



.soc a:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.soc-icon-last{
    margin:0 !important;
}

.soc-facebook {
    color: #3e5b98;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
}

.soc-facebook:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3e5b98;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
}
.soc-facebook:before {
    content:'b';
}
.soc-twitter {
    color: #4da7de;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.soc-twitter:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #4da7de;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.soc-twitter:before {
    content:'a';
}
.soc-instagram {
    color: #9c7c6e;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.soc-instagram:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #9c7c6e;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s;
}
.soc-instagram:before {
    content:'x';
}

/*///////////////PARALLAX///////////////*/
@supports ((perspective: 1px) and (not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch))) {
  /* ... parallax styles ... */

.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--4 {
    transform: translateZ(-.5px) scale(1.5);
/*    position: relative; top: -6150px;*/
    margin-top: 195%;
/*    top: -26%;*/
}

.parallax__layer--3 {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
/*    position: relative; top: -2190px;*/
    margin-top: 69%;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
    transform: translateZ(-1.5px) scale(2.5);
/*    position: relative; top: 2280px;*/
    margin-top: 45%;

}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer--text {
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer--text2 {
    transform: translateZ(-1.3px) scale(2.3);
    }

    .parallax__layer--sm {
        transform: translateZ(-.5px) scale(1.5);
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: Your translateZ on .parallax__layer--4 is messing up your bottom image, remove it and your whitespace disappears

Comment: In my case it looks ok - http://take.ms/tpd7i . Maybe this problem appears on some specific screen resolutions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your website in Firefox and Chrome browser, Firefox seems doesn't have the whitespace problems. The problem only occured in Chrome.

To fix this problems, remove or override the following CSS:

```
/* This is your current CSS style that cause the problems*/

.parallax__layer.parallax__layer--4 {
    transform: translateZ(-.5px) scale(1.5);
}

/* You can remove above or override with this CSS */

.parallax__layer.parallax__layer--4 {
    transform: none;
}
```

Though this will cause your layer slightly down from the original place. It can solve your whitespace problem. Hope this can help you :)

Comment: Ah that totally makes sense! Because it's on the top layer anyways. Thanks!Maybe you can solve another question.. the white space on the left side? I've tried a few things to get rid of that to no avail.

Comment: Your solution seems to have worked although now I have a bit of a scroll glitch where that image goes behind everything else. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
transform: translateZ(-.5px) scale(1.5);
```

from your **parallax__layer parallax__layer--4** layer

Comment: This seems to have worked, although now the layer has jumped behind everything else, any idea why? http://jesseellingson.com/Reflections_Test/

Answer (score 0):

- on class **.parallax__layer parallax__layer--4** don't define **transform**
- on **img** inside **.parallax__layer parallax__layer--4** set *position: absolute;*

You have to also do the second one, otherwise you still have small gap at the bottom (in chrome).

Comment: Removing the transform did help, but now that layer is at the back, any idea why this might be happening? http://jesseellingson.com/Reflections_Test/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my parallax page.  (Mine has a video background, instead.)

I happened upon this really helpful link:  https://www.proteusthemes.com/help/remove-white-space-header-footer/

I tried decreasing the `margin-bottom` on several parts of the page.  But the one that worked was adding it to the id of the video tag's .css.  I played with several values, and finally ended up setting it to a larger negative number:  `margin-bottom: -25rem;`

Now my white margin on the bottom is gone!